# Header layout hard to understand in Firebug

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to look at this page in Firebug:

http://128.48.204.195:3000/

What I am trying to do is make the top-right area with login/signup be all the way to the right, but I am not sure how to do it.  I tried to I surround that stuff with its own div called site_login but it didn't seem to do the trick.

Any idea how to put that stuff on top right further to the right so it looks a little more proportional and symmetrical?

Here is what my css looks like:

```
.banner .site_login {

    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
  float:right;

    right: 0.5em;

    top: 0.5em;

    color: #fff;

}



.banner .site_login a 
{

    color: #fff;

    text-decoration: underline;

}

.banner .site_login a:hover 
{

    color: #ff0;

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Decoupling the styling from .banner worked!!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally commented out the closing div tag  `</div>`

Get that back in there (un-comment it), then position it absolutely (you'll always want it in the same place):

```
 .site_login{position:absolute;width:300px;text-align:right;padding:10px;}
 .banner{position:relative}
```

Comment: Great screen name by the way.  I added the </div> closing tag and tried to add your css, but somehow it didn't do the trick for me. I posted my css.  Is there any particular problem with the way it is now that you can notice?

Comment: @Geeked out: sorry, typo after absolute -- should be a semicolon, not a colon. But Arron's float approach should work well too. Add padding to site_login to distance it from upper and right edge of the header.

Comment: @Geekeout: also forgot to mention this CSS: .banner{position:relative} you'll need that to establish banner as the coordinate grid for the absolute positioning of site_login.

Answer (score 1):

As Faust pointed out, you forgot your closing div tag `</div>`. Also, I added a `float:right` and it seems to work the way you are asking for. [Check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/kqm5b/1/)

Comment: I posted my css.  Something is still not right with it.  Should I decouple the login css from the other html elements?